# Replacing an Associative Array Variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associative-array

Here is the following problem.

My javascript file contains the following code...

```
$(function() {
  var names;
  var names_hash = { };
  // When an user types in a letter in the student name input field
  $(".container").on("keyup", "#term", function(){
    // Here we are submitting the form via AJAX. The form contains necessary
    // Rails code to initiate the AJAX        
    $(this).parents(".student-search-form").submit();
  });

  $(".container").on("click", ".add_nested_fields", function() {
    var term = $("#term").val();

    console.log(names_hash);
  });
});
```

Now when I enter a character into the input field with the id `term` the Rails controller action is called and responds with the following javascript.

FYI, `@group_users_hash` is just a Ruby hash and I have to call `html_safe` so it can be properly converted into a Javascript associative array(yes, I know it's really just an object).

```
names_hash = <%= @group_users_hash.html_safe %>;

console.log(names_hash);
```

So when AJAX finishes, I see that `console.log(names_hash);` has produced on my console

```
Object {1: "Jason"}
```

But when I click on the `.add_nested_fields` calling the `on` event, my console log displays

```
Object {}
```

I don't know why `assoc_array` isn't being updated. What's wrong with my code and how do I fix it?

Comment: You should post the code with your AJAX request as well.

Comment: I did. I'll clarify it though.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you shadowed `assoc_array` with another `var`, but unfortunately all I can do is guess.

Comment: I mean post the full code so we can see it better, when you just have fragments of your code there's no way anyone can help you debug it.

Comment: @jason328 Where's the code that handles/receives the AJAX request? All you did was include some `click` handler and your server code

Comment: @amnotiam I'm betting they don't wait for the AJAX request to come back before executing `console.log()` :) (common asynchronous confusion)

Comment: @Ian: I was thinking that at first, but since the code that doesn't work is in a click handler, they would need to click before the response arrived. But maybe the AJAX is being called from the handler. Who knows...

Comment: @Ian No I have an event that calls the AJAX, I just didn't add it because I know the AJAX is called since I'm being returned 'Object {1: "Jason"}'. I was trying to save you guys from having to view unnecessary code.

Comment: @jason328: With all due respect, if you don't know what causes this issue, then you likely don't know what code is unnecessary. You should provide a full yet minimal working example of the issue.

Comment: @amnotiam Very well. Give me a minute and I'll give you everything.

Comment: @amnotiam Exactly, I just wanted to start a friendly bet and see who's right :) Who knows what it really is...

Comment: @Ian: I'm leaning toward your explanation now that it seems the AJAX is also invoked from an event. I'm guessing it's the same event.

Comment: There it's updated. Would you like for me to post my Rails controller actions as well? I can do development logs too if you want.

Comment: Rails controllers? Logs? No, I still just want the JavaScript code. And you still haven't provided it. Do you really think that a code comment can describe properly a full AJAX request? I don't know why you're so reluctant to simply post your code. You're doing a `.submit()`, so it could be that you the page is reloading, leaving you with a newly loaded JavaScript environment. But again, I'm just guessing since that's all I can do,.

Comment: @amnotiam Looking at the response and the submit on the form I'm guessing he's using a `remote: true` option on the form so you could open up rails unobtrusive javascript file and check the code it uses to make an Ajax for submission to the server. His code is complete enough after the update to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @amnotiam Izuriel is right. Using `remote: true` in the form is the most common way of using AJAX with Rails. You're asking for code I can't give you because it doesn't exist. I'm sorry I can't help you.

Comment: @izuriel: So you're saying that the variable is generated server-side via the submit, and it's a global variable? If so, then why isn't that variable shown in OP's code?

Comment: ...so my comment way up toward the top was correct. Unbelievable. Time for a basic lesson about variable scope.

Comment: @amnotiam With rails (and I'm sure other things but we're talking about rails here) you can respond with Javascript, so the JS is generated on the backend but it's executed on the front end. Your previous comment was partially correct. There is no shadowing going on or mismatched var keywords, just a scope issue.

Comment: @izuriel: Wait... isn't Rails responding with a script that has `names_hash` in the global space, rendering it shadowed by the local `names_hash`?

Comment: @amnotiam You specifically state he's shadowing with a `var` declaration, which is is not - but it is a scope issue which is why I said you're partially correct. Also global scope does not shadow local, local scopes shadow higher scopes.

Comment: @izuriel: Oh, yeah, he is shadowing with a `var` declaration, but I said "another" `var` while it's the current `var` doing the shadowing. Simple issue given clear information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `names_hash` (which you redefine in your return anyways via `var names_hash` and then shadow any higher scoped variables) is not in the same scope as the the one in which you are priting it on click. Thanks to your wrapper function. You're going to need some way - via events or callbacks, etcetera - to access the variable within that scope and set it to the value you wish to use.

**EDIT**

A non-ideal but sample solution to further explain woudl be:

```
var names_hash = {};
$(function() {
  $(".container").on("click", ".add_nested_fields", function() {
    console.log(names_hash);
  });
});
```

And then when your response comes in you simply:

```
names_hash = <%= @group_users_hash.html_safe %>;
```

And then you should be golden. The reason this is not an ideal is because you have your names_hash floating in global scope. It's best to "namespace" such as:

```
(function() {
  // prevent redefining it if it's already defined via another file
  var MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {};

  MyNamespace.names_hash = {};

  window.MyNamespace = MyNamespace;
})();

$(function() {
  $(".container").on("click", ".add_nested_fields", function() {
    console.log(MyNamespace.names_hash);
  });
});
```

And from there you modify your response to:

```
MyNamespace.names_hash = <%= @group_users_hash.html_safe %>;
```

And viola. You've protected global scope and you've also publicized the functions you want to access outside of the wrapper function.

Comment: That was an error on my part when referring to `var names_hash`. I just updated it. But if it's a wrapper issue then I at least know where to start.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out in a second and let you know the results.

Comment: Awesome. It works. Thanks for the thorough explanation. I'll make sure to avoid that problem from now on.

Comment: @jason328 Glad I could help ya out!